# Gson разбор Json Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

Имеется некоторый json, который я получаю через Retrofit.

в Postman он выглядит так

```
{
    "orders": [],
    "info": {
        "message": "Текст",
        "color": "#fec831"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Я не могу его разобрать.

```
data class MyOrdersRemote (
    val orders : Orders2?,
    val success: Boolean,
    val message: String?,
    val info: InfoRemote?
)

data class Orders2(
    var orders: List<OrderX>?
)

data class InfoRemote(
    val message: String,
    val color: String?
)
```

Log

```
D/OkHttp: {"orders":[],"info":{"message":"\u0412\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435! \u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0444\u044b \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u0443\u0440\u044c\u0435\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0443\u044e \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0443 \u043f\u043e \u041c\u0421\u041a \u0438 \u0421\u041f\u0411","color":"#fec831"},"success":true}
    <-- END HTTP (367-byte body)
W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 12 path $.orders
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 12 path $.orders
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:386)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        ... 11 more
D/remoteDataSource: kotlin.Unit
W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 12 path $.orders
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 12 path $.orders
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:386)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        ... 11 more
D/remoteDataSource: kotlin.Unit
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.app.peshkariki, PackageName:com.app.peshkariki
I/.app.peshkarik: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=8114 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: `"orders": []` сам по себе массив, а не объект - то есть нужно объявить его сразу списком, без заворачивания в `Orders2`.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо. А не подскажите, можно ли как нибудь передать data класс в качестве запроса, или обязательно, сначала ложить это в map и потом передавать через FieldMap?

Comment: Можно с аннотацией `@Body`, но как ясно из названия только в качестве тела запроса. В качестве заголовков или query-параметров что-то не припомню.